# Web essentials not showing typescript preview

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

I must be missing something really basic.  I'm playing with Typescript.  Based on this link: http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript I thought that Web Essentials should be giving me a split-pane window so that I could observe the javascript that is being generated for me.

I have my typescript file, but no joy from Web Essentials.  Should the preview pane show up automatically, or is there something I need to do?  (I explored all of the Web Essentials menus, and the link above doesn't say anything about activating the feature.

Setup:

- Visual Studio 2015 w/ Update 1
- TypeScript for Visual Studio installed (version 1.7.6.0 (latest as of
  today))
- Web Essentials 2015.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TypeScript preview pane has been removed from Web Essentials 2015 due to continuously running into conflicts with the TS compiler when new versions come out.

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/53) and hopefully the typescript team will add the feature into the TS tooling in the future.